# How can i make this query with django

Tags: python, django

For a bible site i can make a search with all the verses of the book like 'Genesis', or with the chapter 'Genesis 1' but it goes wrong when i search a verse like 'Genesis 1:1'

How can i split the 1:1 so i can search for the verse also

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = Verse.objects.all()
        if query:
            query = query.split()
            book = query[0]
            object_list = object_list.filter(book__icontains=book)
            if len(query) > 1:
                chapter = query[1]
                object_list = object_list.filter(chapter=chapter)
        return object_list
```

Comment: You need to add the ":" in the split function: query = query.split(":")

Comment: yes thank you. do you know how i can implement that in my code

Comment: Are you asking about the model implementation?

Answer (score 0):

add this after filtering for chapter

```
query[1] = query[1].split(":")
if len(query[1]) > 1
    objects_list = object_list.filter(verse=query[1][1])
```